# How to enable my usercontrol to define controls into its parent form at design-time?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls, design-time

I want my usercontrol to define (declare and initialize) controls inside its parent form class at design-time. For example, the usercontrol (or its associated designer class) should be able to declare a panel "Panel1" into its parent form like this:

```
Partial Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
      Me.MyUserControl1 = New MySolution.MyUserControl
      Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel
      Me.SuspendLayout()
      '          '
      'MyUserControl1
      '
      Me.MyUserControl1.Controls.Add(Me.Panel1)
      Me.MyUserControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 50)
      Me.MyUserControl1.Name = "MyUserControl1"
      Me.MyUserControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(102, 102)
      Me.MyUserControl1.TabIndex = 0
      '
      'Panel1
      '
      Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(1, 1)
      Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
      Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
      Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 1
      '
      'Form1
      '
      Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(399, 262)
      Me.Controls.Add(Me.MyUserControl1)
      Me.Name = "Form1"
      Me.Text = "Form1"
      Me.ResumeLayout(False)
 End Sub

 Friend WithEvents MyUserControl1 As MySolution.MyUserControl
 Friend WithEvents Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
End Class
```

NOTE: this declaration should be dynamic. I know that I can achieve that by adding "Panel1" as a property in my usercontrol but what i need is to add this declaration from within the code, not by providing the item as a property.

Among built-in winforms controls that have this ability, are the TabControl and ListView, for example. Try this scenario: Add a TabControl to a form in the designer, view the designer generated file of the form, you will find that TabPage1 and TabPage2 have been declared and initialized within the form code. If you add another tab and then refer back to the designer generated file, you will find that the TabControl designer has added TabPage3 to the defined items, delete those TabPages from the TabControl, and you will find their associated declarations and initializations deleted from the file source code.

How can this be achieved from within my usercontrol and/or its designer?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible through using function:
   IDesignerHost.CreateComponent
on the designer host interface instance of the control, called from within the code of the control designer (sub initialize or any other method that acts as a verb).
[This is a clear example on how to do it in both Visual Basic and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69374/Generate-InitializeComponent-Code-for-Custom-Conta), 
Many thanks to the author.